# Problems with Graphics in MVC structure

Tags: java, model-view-controller, graphics

I testing to implement graphics into MVC structure but Im a bit stuck. Here is what I got so far. For now I just want to get the red ball to bounce back and forth. And use the button start to start the thread and button stop to stop the thread that runs the GameLoop in the controller.

But I think Im mixing this up a bit. Would very much appreciate some feedback!

Heres what I got so far:

**GameModell** 
suppose to controll the bouncing. If the location of the ball is under 40 px or above 80 px - multiply the locationX with -1 to make the ball change direction

**GameView**
Here Im putting the labels on a JFrame. I also want to display the buttons start and stop to controll the thread but I guess they are hidden by the JPanel in **TheGraphics** class

**GameController**
Starts and stops the thread with ActionListeners. Contains the GameLoop

**TheGraphics**
Paints the ball and controll the direction

I guess I got a lot of thing that are all wrong but this is the best I can do at the moment. Would very much apreciate some help!

Thanks!

**MAIN:**

```
public class MVCgame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameModel gm = new GameModel();        
        GameView gv = new GameView();
        GameController gc = new GameController(gm, gv);
    }
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
public class GameModel {
    private int multi = 1;


    public void setMulti(int locX) {
        if(locX < 40 || locX > 80) {
            multi = multi * -1;
        }
    }

    public int multi() {
        return multi;
    }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameView extends JFrame {

    private JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    private JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    TheGraphics gr = new TheGraphics();

    public GameView() {
        add(jp);
        add(gr);

        jp.add(start);
        jp.add(stop);
        setSize(250, 250);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addListener(ActionListener theListener) {
        start.addActionListener(theListener);
        stop.addActionListener(theListener);
    }

    public JButton getStart() {

        return start;
    }

    public JButton getStop() {
        return stop;
    }

    // GUESS I SHOULD PUT THIS IN THE VIEW???
    public void paintEllipse(Graphics theG) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) theG;
        g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GameController implements Runnable {

    GameView gv;
    GameModel gm;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public GameController(GameModel gm, GameView gv) {
        this.gv = gv;
        this.gm = gm;
        gv.addListener(theListener);
        start();
    }

    ActionListener theListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == gv.getStart()) {
                start();
                System.out.println("PLAY = ");
            } else if (e.getSource() == gv.getStop()) {
                stop();
                System.out.println("STOP = ");
            }
        }
    };

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        thread.interrupt();
        running = false;
    }

    // GameLoop
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 10) {
            // tick();
                delta--;

                // repainting the graphics
                gv.gr.drawer();
                gm.setMulti(gv.gr.drawer());
                System.out.println("gv.gr.drawer() = " + gv.gr.drawer() + " gm.multi() " + gm.multi());
                // I want to use this value in the model to change the direction                
            }
            if (running) {
            }
            frames++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THE GRAPHICS:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TheGraphics extends JPanel {

    private int locX = 40;

    public TheGraphics() {

    }

    public int drawer() {
        locX++;

        repaint();
        return locX;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        g2d.fillOval(locX, 30, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: `drawer()` in `TheGraphics` should not be adjusting any state. You shouldn't even have location in the graphics section, it should be in your model. Right now, if the location goes past your bounds, you inverse the location (if the ball reaches 80, it gets set to -80). Instead, you should be inversing the velocity at which the ball is traveling. Since direction doesn't seem to be a factor here, all you need to do is inverse the speed: to move the ball, add speed to the location. Once ball has reached location, inverse speed so it starts moving in the other direction.

Comment: Isn't this a question that should be asked on codereview by the way?

Answer (score 1):

> GameModell suppose to controll the bouncing. If the location of the ball is under 40 px or above 80 px - multiply the locationX with -1 to make the ball change direction

```
public void setMulti(int locX) {
    if(locX < 40 || locX > 80) {
        multi = multi * -1;
    }
}
```

Really bad idea. You should always check position *and* direction (sign(speed)). Otherwise, your object might get stuck out of bounds always changing direction without moving from place forever.

Apart from this, using the MVC concept is overkill in my eyes and shouldn't be used in such a small project nor in a game. In a game, you should more or less put all three together. Of course you *can*, but the advantages and disadvantages of the MVC concept don't fit the needs of a game in many ways (except for the GUI, perhaps).

Your main loop might look something like this (you kind of did this already, but why is the tick() commented out in your code?):

```
while (running) {
   update(); // Update all game objects
   paint(); // Paint them all
}
```

Each game object will have its own update() and paint() implementation. You **absolutely** need to separate the logic of update and paint, even if they are in the same class. So this one:

```
public int drawer() {
    locX++;

    repaint();
    return locX;
}
```

is an absolute no-go.

**Edit:** (Referring your update answer)

You are using the method `location()` for different purposes. According to the Java name convention, you should rename it `getLocation()` and `setLocation()` depending on the use to clarify the code.

(Even if this is not really MVC anymore, I'd let `GameFrame` implement `ActionListener` instead of specifying it as variable of `GameController`.)

One thing you should really change is this one:

```
private int locX = 0;

public void location(int loc) {
    this.locX = (int) loc;
}
```

Basically, you are duplicating the location value every frame and create unused redundant data. Another problem is, that this might work fine for only one variable, but what if you add more than the position to your model later on? Instead `TheGraphics` has to render on an instance of the data model, not its values. As long you are using one `GameModel`

```
private GameModel model; // set value once at initialisation
```

and rendering its values in `paintComponent` will work fine, but if you want to add more than one `GameModel` (handling GameModel more like a GameObjectModel), you will need to pass it as parameter in the paint method.

```
public void update() {
    repaint();
}
```

Remove it and try getting around without. A method called from one place forwarding to a different method is a bad idea most of the time, especially if it obfuscates the functionality with a different name.

```
            gv.gr.update();
            gv.gr.location(gm.location());
```

You are first repainting your image and then setting the location? Basically, your game runs one frame behind all the time. Swap that order.

```
            gv.gr.location(gm.location());
            gv.gr.repaint();
```

Will be fine (I already said about `location()`).

Comment: MVC exists solely to enforce separation of concerns (the graphics designer should not have to worry about the business logic required by the software, and any events should be dispatched to their respective controllers for mediation), which is still *extremely* beneficial in gaming software, especially as it grows. The problem with games structured the way you're suggesting is events are dispatched to the loop, which then require dispatching to the correct entity. Instead, events could be dispatched directly to the entity's controller, avoiding excess delegation.

Comment: I won't argue with you about if, when, and how to use the MVC concept in game development. This decision has to be made on a per-game basis by the team. Using it in the "game" of this question is nothing more than an example of the term "overengineering".

Comment: Thanks. Yes of course is this to much work for such a simple task as a red dot bouncing back and forth :) My maingoal is to practise and clearify the structure of mvc for myself. Im pretty new to java and also got a bit confused with the implementation of the graphics. Thanks for replies!